# SBT ignoring proxy repository

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I have a custom `repositories` file that points to our internal Nexus repo:

```
[repositories]
  local
  ivy-proxy-releases: https://nexus.ci.build.org.internal:8443/repository/ivy-public/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  maven-proxy-releases: https://nexus.ci.build.org.internal:8443/repository/maven-public/
  maven-proxy-snapshots: https://nexus.ci.build.org.internal:8443/repository/maven-snapshots/
```

That's all very standard but I can see from the output that SBT first connects to the Proxy repository and then tries to talk to an external repository:

```
[SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.13.16!test-agent.jar (154ms)
downloading https://nexus.ci.build.org.internal:8443/repository/maven-public/org/scala-sbt/test-interface/1.0/test-interface-1.0.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0!test-interface.jar (15ms)
downloading https://nexus.ci.build.org.internal:8443/repository/ivy-public/org.scala-sbt/apply-macro/0.13.16/jars/apply-macro.jar ...
...
[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.6.6 ...[0m
[A
[2K[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.6.6 ...[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0mServer access Error: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.6.6/ivys/ivy.xml[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0mServer access Error: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.6.6/ivys/ivy.xml[0m
[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-routes-compiler_2.10;2.6.6 ...[0m
[A
```

Now why is that? Even if, in this case, `com.typesafe.play` doesn't exist in our Nexus, shouldn't SBT just fail and not go to any external repositories?

Answer (score 0):

Ivy and sbt are the built in resolvers. I'm not sure if their URLs can be overriden. Instead of overriding them, perhaps you could try adding your server as an additional resolver to the repo?

Worst case, you could provide the jars directly.